# How can I create this Logo in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I made this using a combination of LaTeX and powerpoint. I was wondering how it can be made purely in LaTeX code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us -- as usual here -- the short compilable tex code you have so far ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Here is a possibility.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[yscale=2,xscale=1.2,rotate=-5] (int) {$\int$};
\node (H1) at ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]int.east) {$\mathbb{H}$};
\node (H2) at ([yshift=1mm,xshift=1mm]int.west) {$\mathbb{H}$};
\node[circle,draw,thick,fit=(int) (H1) (H2),inner sep=-1pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[yscale=2.4,xscale=1.2,rotate=-10] (int) {$\int$};
\node (H1) at ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-2pt]int.east) {$\mathbb{H}$};
\node (H2) at ([yshift=1mm,xshift=2pt]int.west) {$\mathbb{H}$};
\node[circle,draw,thick,fit=(int) (H1) (H2),inner sep=-5pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please consider showing us what you tried in your future posts.

Answer (score 4):

Picture mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\newcommand{\hinth}{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox0{$\displaystyle\int$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr\wd0+\dp0}
  \begin{picture}(1.4,1.4)
  \put(0.7,0.7){\makebox(0,0){$\displaystyle\int$}}
  \put(0.7,0.7){\circle{1.4}}
  \put(0.4,0.9){\makebox(0,0){$\mathbb{H}$}}
  \put(1,0.5){\makebox(0,0){$\mathbb{H}$}}
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\hinth

\end{document}
```

[image]